# Google Sheets Script - Select next row + merge range?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a menu list that will add in X number of rows, and merge columns H>M of the new rows added (row by row - not the entire block). I can't work out how to select the active row +1 or active row +2 etc and then move along the appropriate number of cells.

Below is the script I have thus far for the UI and adding the rows, I'm tying myself in knots trying to merge H>M of the new rows I insert!

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Planning Functions')
      .addItem('Add 1 Row', 'add1row')
  .addItem('Add 2 Rows', 'add2row')
      .addToUi();
}

function add1row() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var ar = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
  ss.insertRowsAfter(ar, 1); 
}
function add2row() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var ar = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
  ss.insertRowsAfter(ar, 2);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Planning Functions')
      .addItem('Add 1 Row', 'add1row')
  .addItem('Add 2 Rows', 'add2row')
      .addToUi();
}

function add1row() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ar = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var mergeRange = sheet.getRange(ar+1,8,1,6);
  ss.insertRowsAfter(ar, 1); 
  mergeRange.mergeAcross();
}
function add2row() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ar = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var mergeRange = sheet.getRange(ar+1,8,2,6);
  ss.insertRowsAfter(ar, 2);
  mergeRange.mergeAcross();
}
```

Comment: This is great, I was incorrectly trying to specify each range and merge them but I see your solution of mergeacross is much better. Thank you so much!